# OnLoad client event for Image control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, onload

I need to bind client side `onLoad` event with ASP.Net Image control. I have tried it for quite some time with no success.

Function Name `onload="onLoadFunction(this)"`

Script:

```
function onLoadFunction(img) {
     $(img).css("visibility", "visible"); // Using jQuery
     // img.style.visibility = "visible"; // Using just javascript.
 }
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgTopFourImg2" runat="server" width="170px" height="112px" CssClass="ArticleImgHP" border="0" ImageUrl="hello.jpg" OnLoad="onLoadFunction(this)" />
```

It is not working for me i would appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: This is actually related to my previous question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227254/image-progress-bar-for-images-being-downloaded-in-website-not-working-with-aprop/10228540#comment13141900_10228540

Comment: If you check the link in my last comment you will get the complete picture..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OnLoad attribute is used to add an event handler the Load event, which is a server side event, not client side.

If you want create the onload attribute of the generated image element, you need to use Attributes collection

```
imgTopFourImg2.Attributes["onload"] = "onLoadFunction(this)";
```

**EDIT from comments**

Since the image is inside a repeater item this is not available in code behind. Handle [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event:

```
void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

          // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.

          // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
          if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item 
                  || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
             {

                var imgTopFourImg2 = e.Item.FindControl("imgTopFourImg2") as Image;
                if (imgTopFourImg2 != null)
                    imgTopFourImg2.Attributes["onload"] = "onLoadFunction(this)";
             }
          }
       }
```

Comment: This image is inside a repeater control how can i add for that. I tried it gave me error control not found..

Answer (score 3):

`$("img #xyz").bind("load", function () { $(this).css("visibility", "visible"); });`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#imgTopFourImg2").bind("load", function () { $(this).show(); });
```

It's worth looking into the `show()` and `hide()` methods, since you're already using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img #id").bind("load", function () { $(this).css("visibility", "visible"); });
```

Comment: too heavy - this will bind all images, and change all images in a page.

Comment: By editing your post/answer you made a duplicate answer here.