# Client side events for Asp.net controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have image as below

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgLogo" Style="border-width: 0px; max-width: 100%; max-height: 200px;" onerror="showInvalidImageMessage();" onload="imageChanged()"/>
```

here I want to fire `JavaScript` event how ever it is looking for server side handler.

I can't use `JQuery`'s `on` or `bind` or `live` because these are not working in my scenario as this image control is coming dynamically.

Focusing on client side event we use `onclientclick` for ASP button in the same way I tried `onclientload` which doesn't work. I want to use pure `JS`. Possible?

Comment: try using `javascript:showInvalidImageMessage();`

Comment: if you insist on calling js from server side events then, let the server side event fired and call js from that event will let you to handle your scenarios  OR you could also use jquery.click event.

Answer (score 0):

The Image control lets you work with images from server code. Use the Image control to display any valid image supported by the requesting browser on the Web page.

The OnLoad attribute is used to add an event handler the Load event, which is a server side event, not client side.

refer this

[OnLoad client event for Image control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229625/onload-client-event-for-image-control)